# Check android keystore keypass for correctness

Tags: android, keytool, jarsigner

I'm automating some things that involve the android keytool and jarsigner. The tool takes a keystore, the password for the keystore, the alias name, and the password for the alias / key, and I'm trying to find a way to explicitly check to see if the supplied password for the alias / key is correct.

Any ideas? Also, I need to check it without a jar file to sign - getting that file in my context is lengthy, so I want to abort sooner rather than later.

Comment: can you change the correct answer?

Comment: Yep! Although but damn it's been awhile since I touched any of this.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You can also check if the password is correct without attempting to change the password. I did it by listing the properties of the keystore with this command:

```
keytool -list -keystore <keystorefile> -storepass <passwordtocheck>
```

Comment: I am getting this - **The syntax of the command is incorrect.**

Comment: Note that this doesn't test correctness of the alias password

Comment: @VijayKumar The answer below uses `keytool -keypasswd` to try and change the alias' password (to the same password), which will fail if the password is incorrect.

Answer (score 33):

You can do it a couple of ways:

A. With `keytool`

If you run the command `keytool -keypasswd -keystore <keystore> -alias <alias> -storepass <storepass> -keypass <keypass> -new <keypass>` then you will get the error `Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect` if the keystore password is wrong, or the error `Cannot recover key` if the alias password is wrong. Unfortunately the return code is 1 in both cases, so you will need to do parsing of the program's output if you want to be smart about the type of error.

B. With a small Java program

Something along these lines:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(keystore)) {
    ks.load(fis, ksPw.toCharArray());
}

ks.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(aliasPw.toCharArray()));
```

will fail at line 4 with a `java.io.IOException` if the key store password is wrong, or with a `java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException` at line 7 if the alias password is wrong.

Comment: You save my day! My password was corrected but I was wrong with alias. Thanks!