# How to reuse an android key to release application

Tags: android, android-keystore

I created a key for my application on my laptop and released my application. Now I just copied that key into a flash and now I want to reuse it again, But I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key key0 from store "E:\Rasad\Key\RasadKey.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

I just test this path again with a new key and it happened again!

What is the problem?

Thankyou for your answers.

Comment: You might have provided wrong Password.

Comment: Did you try to read "key alias" without entering the "Key store password"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891182/keytool-error-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect

Comment: @Chandankushwaha No I'm sure about this

Answer (score 0):

Copy the ".jks" file and enter the same password you have used before. When generating signed apk, choose existing instead of new. Hope it helps

Comment: I just did that, But It doesn't work and give me the error that I mentioned in the question!

Comment: are you using the same alias name? as everything should be same

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that you have provided either the wrong key store password, or the wrong key password. There's an easy way to check with `keytool`:

[Check android keystore keypass for correctness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945936/check-android-keystore-keypass-for-correctness)